# Convert an array of 1/0 to number using shift

Tags: arrays

how can i convert an array of 0 and 1 to a decimal number without any special functions?

```
Array[7] = 0
Array[6] = 0
Array[5] = 0
Array[4] = 0
Array[3] = 0
Array[2] = 0
Array[1] = 0
Array[0] = 1

    value=0
    for i=0 to 7
        value=value or Array[i]
        value=value shl 1
    next
```

Running the above codes returns value = 2 instead of 1.
What is the error here?

Thanks

Comment: What language would that be?

Comment: Do you have a particular programming language in mind?  Arrays of bits often get special treatment in a programming language, especially if the array would fit into a supported integer type (e.g. , less than 64 bits)  Do you have a particular length of array in mind?

Comment: But even language agnostic: You are doing the `shift left` after every bit you handle. So you are doing 8 `shl` operations instead of only 7 (you must not shift the 2^0 bit!)

Comment: Furthermore I assume `Array[0]` should be the "lowest" and `Array[7]` should be the "highest" bit. Because otherwise you couldn't expect `1` as output. But if that's the case, you are working in the wrong direction, because `Array[0]` is shifted multiple times (so I wonder how that would return `2` and not `256`)

Answer (score 1):

Do the `or` and `shl` in the opposite order:

```
        value=value shl 1
        value=value or Array[i]
```

Comment: That still whould shilft `Array[0]` seven times, so I wonder how that original code would result in `2` and not `256`